# How to remotely connect to AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, alexa-skills-kit

I have to connect AWS Elasticsearch with Alexa. According to a file, I have to put

```
client = new ElasticSearchClient("your.elastic.url", 9300, "your.cluster.name");
```

What is the elastic URL and 9300 for my AWS hosted ES Cluster?

Comment: AWS ES does not offer the possibility to connect via TCP. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274624/using-elasticsearch-transport-client-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-aes/49277382#49277382). You can only connect via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, AWS ES does not offer the possibility to connect via TCP.

**TCP transport**

> The service supports HTTP on port 80, but does not support TCP
>   transport.

[developerguide aes-supported-resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-resources.html)

But you can try this [how-to-use-java-high-level-rest-client-with-spring-boot-to-talk-to-aws-elasticsearch](https://medium.com/echoenergy/how-to-use-java-high-level-rest-client-with-spring-boot-to-talk-to-aws-elasticsearch-9e12571df93e).

Another thing, it totally depends upon the underlying library that is https://github.com/unterstein/elastic-alexa you can give it try with https with out port.

As per your question you can get AWS ES cluster details and endpoint here.

ES -> Dashboard -> select domain

in the Top, you see cluster name and below in endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will definitely go through the links you sent. One question, 9300 is for normal ES, what is the equivalent in AWS ES?

Comment: AWS use https its mean 443. check the screenshot.